# SSRS Anchor Report to centre of screen

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

Morning Everyone,

Can some please confirm if it is at all possible to anchor sections of your report to parts of the screen alike you can within C# Winforms?

I would liketo anchor logos to the top left, tables to the middle ect.. but at the moment I have not been able to find out how to do it. Is it possibly custom code?

Regards,

Richard

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly possible to do using standard Reporting Services features.

Since it is possible to have any kind of object within the cells of a tablix (even another tablix), perhaps you could try something like this:

Create one big tablix with 3x3 cells but without any row or column groups. Make this tablix fill your entire report width and height. Then, use the alignments of each cell to "anchor" content however you want it.

It's not pretty, but it might work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your input Dan. If its not too pretty is there any of standard to try achieve the best possible layout possible for several resolutions if anchoring is not the way forward?